# Socket io works on page reload only

Tags: express, websocket, socket.io, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm using socket.io in my nuxt 3 project .

this is what the setup looks like (defined as a nuxt plugin):

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((context) => {
  let socket = null; // Declare socket variable
const {status,data} = useAuth()
  // Function to generate dynamic headers
  const getHeaders = () => {
    const authToken = useCookie('auth:token'); // Assuming you're using Nuxt Auth module
    if (authToken.value) {
      return {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken.value}`,
      };
    }
    return {};
  };

  // Function to create socket.io client instance with dynamic headers
  const createSocketInstance = () => {
    socket = io('http://localhost:4501', {
      extraHeaders: getHeaders(), // Call getHeaders function to get dynamic headers
    });
    return socket;
  };

  // Function to update socket headers when user authentication state changes
  const updateSocketHeaders = () => {
    if (status.value === "authenticated") {
      // If user is authenticated, update socket headers with new token
      socket.io.opts.extraHeaders = getHeaders();
    } else {
      // If user is not authenticated, clear socket headers
      socket.io.opts.extraHeaders = {};
    }
  };

  // Listen to user authentication state changes
  watch(status,(nv,ov)=>{
    if (socket) {
      updateSocketHeaders(); // Update socket headers when authentication state changes
    }
  })

  // Create socket instance when the plugin is initialized
  createSocketInstance();

  return {
    provide: {
      io: socket, // Provide socket instance
    },
  };
});
```

and i have a global middleware that connects to the socket :

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { $io } = useNuxtApp();
    const { status, data } = useAuth();
    
    if (status.value === "authenticated" && process.client) {
        try {
            if (!$io.connected) {
                await $io.connect();
                $io.emit('joinRoom',data.value.user.id)

            }
            $io.on('error', (error: any) => {
                console.error('Socket connection error:', error);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error connecting to socket:', error);
        }
    }
});
```

and in my express backend :

```
  io.on('connection', async (socket: Socket) => {

    if (socket.handshake && socket.handshake.auth) {
     // ^ this condition is true , no issues on the auth side
      getApplicationsCountByDay(io,socket.handshake.auth)
     
    //   ^ this emits 'applicationEvent'
    // works only on page reload with  setTimeOut() without  setTimeOut() it does not trigger at all
```

the issue is getApplicationsCountByDay is only excuting on page refresh .

it does not trigger if i leave the page and come back to it.

this is how i handle it in my page :

```
onMounted(async ()=>{

    $io.on('applicationEvent', (receivedData: any) => {
        console.log('ok count');
        dataValues.value = receivedData.map((item: any) => item.count);
      });
    
})
```

I cant really figure out whats the issue here .. other events are working if i moved between pages without reloading .

is there any idea what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you registered the plugin with the `.client` suffix?

Comment: it is registered. i solved it by emitting an event from the client to the server and then returning the getApplicationsCountByDay()